# Allowing a website service only through Chrome extension

Tags: javascript, php, google-chrome-extension

I have a small website written in PHP, but that is not important for now. I am curious, is there a way to allow access to my website only if the user has my Chrome extension installed?

For example, from the extension, let's say when I click on the popup button, I send a request to a server, verifying that it is that a request coming from that extension, and from there serving me a webpage. If the user goes right to the page (www.example.com) it will be denied, because it is sent from the Chrome search bar.

I want to know if there is some unique number or something, that can be assigned to an extension and send that info on the server (that also knows that number), comparing them, and if they are the same, serve the page.

Comment: You can check the 'Origin' HTTP header, or you can set a custom HTTP header in your extension manually. However it's not 100% reliable as another extension can spoof anything your extension can send.